# Interpretation of coefficients in HAR model

Tags: regression, time-series, linear-model, volatility

I'm performing the HAR model by Corsi. However, I don't quite understand what Corsi means by this in the original paper.

He writes:

> It is worth noticing that if we accept the interpretation that realized volatilities
> aggregated over different horizons are reasonable proxies for volatilities generated
> by the corresponding market components, an interesting by-product of this simple
> OLS regression is a direct estimate of the market component weights, that is, a ready evaluation of the contribution of each market component to the overall
> market activity. For instance, in the USD/CHF and S&P500 series, it seems that
> the importance of the market components decreases with the horizon of the aggregation.

In my case I am performing the HAR model on the SP500 index realized volatility. I found that the weekly volatility component had yields the highest value, the daily the second highest and monthly the lowest, but I'm not sure what Corsi means, when he says that we can interpret them as their contribution to overall market activity?